# Correct way to use QLPreviewController with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, qlpreviewcontroller

I have CoreData app that stores some BLOBs in external files ("allows external storage" flag).

Files are images, PDFs, excel files etc. I wanna use `QLPreviewController` ti preview it. But it does not support CoreData from scratch. So, I should first copy file to tmp folder. I am sure there should be better way to do that.
Does there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for `QLPreviewItem` the URL returned by `previewItemURL` must be a file URL.

Thus, you must be able to give it a URL for a file that lives on disk.  Apple does not provide an official way to get the URL for data stored externally.  Furthermore, "smaller" files would be stored as a BLOB in the SQL database anyway.

The two most viable options are to either copy the contents into a temporary file when needed, or store the file on disk yourself, and keep the URL (or better yet... a unique identifier) in the core data model.

I'd go with the second method.

If you store the files in a subdirectory of the directory containing your core data store, you can just keep a UUID in the database.  You can then identify the file, even if you want to move it to a different location, and you don't have to go change all the entities in the store.

Let's say you have a directory named "externalFiles" in the same directory as your persistent store.

If you used a special entity, you could add two simple attributes (identifier and title) for the particular item.  The identifier can be the string representation of `NSUUID`.

You will probably already want to get at the URL...

```
- (NSURL*)URL {
    // Separated on multiple lines for readability
    NSString *identifier = [self valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    NSURL *url = self.objectID.persistentStore.URL;
    url = [url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"externalFiles"];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:identifier];
    return url;
}
```

You can then make your `NSManagedObject` subclass conform to `QLPreviewItem` protocol by implementing the two methods `previewItemURL` and `previewItemTitle`.

```
- (NSURL*)previewItemURL {
    return self.URL;
}

- (NSURL*)previewItemTitle {
    return self.title;
}
```

And then, you can just pass your core data instances to the `QLPreviewControllerDataSource` because they can now be treated as `QLPreviewItem`s.